# Where is the possessive apostrophe placed?

Tags: grammar

In the following partial sentence, is the apostrophe placement  on “vice-president’s” correct or should it go after the s: “Vice-presidents’ ”

In the filling of vacancies in the five (5) vice-president’s office’s...

(I’m aware that there should not be an apostrophe in “offices”)

Comment: If you are aware that *offices* should not have an apostrophe, I don't know why you gave it one.

Comment: It wasn't my sentence structure, I was correcting a poorly written by-laws change.

Answer (score 2):

Since there are [multiple](https://www.bing.com/search?q=define%20plural&pc=MOZI&form=MOZLBR) vice presidents, the noun would be **vice president*s***.

If you are saying then that that group of people, the vice presidents, own something, then yes it would be, perhaps as your hunch:

> vice presidents' offices

However this is more like a literal possessive, as if you were saying:

> The 5 vice presidents' offices were burned in an arson attack.

If instead you mean to say that you are filling a position/s (or an "office"), then you might consider restructuring the sentence, such as:

> In filling the vacancies for the offices of our 5 vice presidents, *[we reviewed many qualified applicantions...]*